# Rails 5 select where with no id reference on third model, using active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have 3 models, Client, Book, ClientBook. ClientBook belongs to Client and Book. this model (ClientBook) keeps all the books that a client already bougth or read.

I want to select from Books, I want to select all the books that the client did not buy or read yet, using active record, example:

```
@books_to_offer = Book.all
```

I hope to be clear, if you need more information, please ask. thanks

Comment: Try this: `Book.where.not(id: @client.books.pluck(:id))` (assuming you have correct `has_many` declarations in `Client` class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
# models/book.rb

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :client_books
  has_many :clients, through: :client_books
  scope :unread_by, -> (client) { where.not(id: client.books) }
end


# models/client.rb

class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :client_books
  has_many :books, through: :client_books
end
```

Now you can do:

```
>> client = Client.find(1)
>> Book.unread_by(client)
#> <ActiveRecord::Relation ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a has_many through(Client > ClientBook > Book), you could try:

```
Books.where.not(Client.first.book_ids)
```

References:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions

Comment: class Client has_many: books, through: : client_books.  Is this correct?

Comment: The method illustrated here will run two queries: one to obtain book ids, and another to determine books that don't have a relation. It is possible to do this with a single query. See my answer, which uses one query and also uses a scope to allow you to determine which client to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
@books_to_offer = Book.where.not(id: @client.books.select(:id))
```

Using `#select` allows Rails to combine this into a single query, preventing the client book objects or even ids from being queried into memory first.

Comment: You don't need `select(:id)`. You can just use `where.not(id: @client.books)`.

Comment: Indeed. I intentionally used it because it makes the code a bit less strange (by not having to ask "how does an id equal a book object?") It also works for all cases (i.e. if the column is not `id`.)

Comment: Interesting. Do you also specify, for example, `split(' ')` instead of just `split`, because that also works for all cases? Or `inject(:+)` instead of `sum`? Not saying it's wrong, just curious why you wouldn't use the shortcut built into the language.

Comment: I explained it already in the previous comment. It's unlikely I can explain it any simpler than that. The shortcut is slightly misleading, as it can look like a mistake at first. There's a clear disparity between the key and the value. That's not true for any of your other examples. (Although if the delimiter to `#split` is likely to change, I might explicate or even extract it on a case by case basis.)

Comment: That's an interesting philosophy. What do you do for path helpers? Do you write `client_path(@client.id)` or `client_path(@client)`? If I understand your philosophy correctly, you should prefer the first, as it is more explicit and more clearly states what you want to do (build a path that includes the client id). But in practice I nearly always see the second variation used.